# A Question on tangential quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider this tangential quadrilateral 
[image]

Is there any relation between angle $\angle XOY$ with sides $b2$ or $a2$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Let $\angle XOY=2\theta$, and let $P$ be the intersection point of two sides $a2,b2$.

Since $PX=PY$, two triangle $POX, POY$ are congruent. So, $\angle POX=\angle POY=\theta.$

So, letting $PX=PY=p$, we have
$$\tan\theta=\frac{p}{r}.$$

Hence, we have an relation as
$$\tan(\angle XOY)=\tan(2\theta)=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}=\frac{2(p/r)}{1-(p/r)^2}=\frac{2rp}{r^2-p^2}.$$